# Writing JSON String as String in Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am creating an app which uses volley. I used JsonObjectRequest() to send Json object through volley. Thus I had to create Jason Object from values taken from Edit text.

```
btn_enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SN1 = inputsn.getText().toString();
                Name1 = inputname.getText().toString();

            }
        });

        JSONObject jsonMenu= null;
        try {

            jsonMenu = new JSONObject("");//string is to be added here
            Toast.makeText(Add.this,"Made Obj",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Add","Error");
        }
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,jsonMenu, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("MainActivity",response.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Add.this,"Response Received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Add.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }
        });
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
```

Here, [{"SN":1,"Name":"Ajeeb"}] values 1 and Ajeeb is to be replaced by values of SN1 and Name1 respectively.Such that I can add it to Java code

```
JSONObject jsonMenu = new JSONObject("\\String goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create property for json object and than as it to your Json Object

`jsonMenu.addProperty("SN", SN1);
 jsonMenu.addProperty("Name", Name);`

This will result in `{"SN":1,"Name":"Ajeeb"}`

And if you want to create an array for it 
`JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
   jsonArray.put(jsonMenu);`

This will result  in `[{"SN":1,"Name":"Ajeeb"}]`